# change the signs in the number field

Tags: c

How to change the signs in the number field?

```c
void swap_sign(const int size, int array[]) {
  if (array[] != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (array[i] == /* - */ ) {
        //turn the sign to + and save to the field
      } else if (array[i] == /* + */ ) {
        //turn the sign to - and save to the field
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "number field"? Change from what to what? `array[i]= -array[i]` will negate the array element, but it should be obvious from the basic math.

Comment: int number_field[] = {1.2,3,0,-1,-2,-3}

Comment: and I need to change the signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have commented things out in the for loop, but switching signs is achieved with just multiplying the minus sign.

`array[i] = -array[i];`

```c
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
   array[i] = -array[i];
}
```

Comment: is it so easy? thank you